# TextureView transforms on Android -Problem with Scale and crop

Tags: android, camera, crop, textureview

I have a TextureView with a fixed width and height and I want to show a camera preview inside of it. I need to crop the camera preview so that it doesn't look stretched inside my TextureView. How to do the cropping?

Here is my code--------------------------------------------------------------

```
    private int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 101;
    private final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.CAMERA", "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};
    TextureView textureView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textureView = findViewById(R.id.view_finder);

        if(allPermissionsGranted()){
            startCamera(); //start camera if permission has been granted by user
        } else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
        }
    }

    private void startCamera() {

        CameraX.unbindAll();

        Rational aspectRatio = new Rational (textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight());
        Size screen = new Size(textureView.getWidth(), textureView.getHeight()); //size of the screen


        PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder()
                                    .setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)
                                    .setTargetResolution(screen)
                                    //.setLensFacing(CameraX.LensFacing.FRONT)
                                    .build();
        Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig);

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
                new Preview.OnPreviewOutputUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onUpdated(Preview.PreviewOutput output){
                        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) textureView.getParent();
                        parent.removeView(textureView);
                        parent.addView(textureView, 0);

                        textureView.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                        updateTransform();
                    }
                });


        ImageCaptureConfig imageCaptureConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY)
                .setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();
        final ImageCapture imgCap = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig);

        findViewById(R.id.imgCapture).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
                imgCap.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                        String msg = "Pic captured at " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.UseCaseError useCaseError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                        String msg = "Pic capture failed : " + message;
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if(cause != null){
                            cause.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //bind to lifecycle:
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, preview, imgCap);
    }

    private void updateTransform(){
        Matrix mx = new Matrix();
        float w = textureView.getMeasuredWidth();
        float h = textureView.getMeasuredHeight();

//        textureView.getTransform(txform);
//        txform.setScale((float) = videoWidth / viewWidth, (float) videoHeight / viewHeight);// aspect ratio
//        textureView.setTransform(txform); // apply matrix

        float cX = w / 2f;
        float cY = h / 2f;

        int rotationDgr;
        int rotation = (int)textureView.getRotation();

        switch(rotation){
            case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                rotationDgr = 0;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                rotationDgr = 90;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                rotationDgr = 180;
                break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                rotationDgr = 270;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }

    mx.postRotate((float)rotationDgr, cX, cY);
    textureView.getTransform(mx);
    textureView.setTransform(mx);
}
```

expected result

[image]

Comment: Just came across your post because I searched a calculation behind it. When in landscape mode you can use `textureView.scaleY = 1.66f` to scale it to "normal"

When using portrait mode you can use scaleX respectively. I am not sure why 1.66 works, aspect ratio of my phone is 2.43 so that isn't the case also. Just wanted to give a bit of information on this topic